# Codificar string en javascript

Tags: javascript

lo que deseo hacer es ocultar la contraseña de una API en mi código JS que actualmente está en texto plano guardada en una variable de tipo string fácilmente accesible si vemos el código desde un navegador web.

```
var settings = {
    
//more stuff//

    // Esta es la API key que deseo codificar u ofuscar.
    'api_key': '25lr85917957z919933464544rrbeebf',
 
   //more stuff//

};

//more stuff

const API_KEY = settings.api_key;

//more stuff
```

Comment: Este tipo de datos (secret) no deben ir en el código Javascript, deben ser manejadas en el backend. Mientras más información puedas proporcionar, será mejor ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: En realidad me di cuenta que mi API key era usada por otros usuarios ya que tiene un límite diario de uso de 10.000 y siempre estaba completado. No he intentado hacer nada porque no se como solucionarlo. Mi web es tradicional html + css + javascript. También uso php para recuperar datos de otra web (Shoutcast). No se como servir ese dato desde el backend porque este no existe, salvo para el servidor shoutcast de la radio donde tengo acceso como root y puedo incorporarlo y que luego sea leido por el JS, pero no tengo idea de como lograrlo.

Comment: Todo tu código de html/css/js que esté en tú página siempre será visible, necesitas que el usuario de tu webpage se identifique ya sea ingresando los datos manualmente o por medio de un archivo. Debes de crear en el servidor una ruta en donde los usuarios de la webpage puedan enviar un token/identificador/clave con la cual identificarse y luego **el servidor** debe de usar la llave API para obtener los datos y devolverlos de vuelta al usuario. Sin que el usuario de la webpage sepa cuál es la API key.

Comment: @FranAcuna gracias por tus comentarios, esa API key se usa para acceder a una API que me permite mostrar la letra de la canción /lyrics que suena en la radio online en mi web. Soy principiante y lo veo algo engorroso o difícil de implementar eso. Pensé que ya existía alguna forma fácil de hacerlo sin tener que requerirle a cada usuario que ingrese a oir la radio que ingrese algún código o algo. No existe alguna forma de codificar la API key en base 64 y decodificarla desde el servidor ? Si se te ocurre algo envíame ejemplos de código para el JS y para el servidor. Gracias

Comment: Si claro, si se puede codificar la llave y que luego el servidor la decodifique para usar el API. Lo que importa es que el único que tenga la llave es el servidor. A menos que  tu plan sea codificarla en la página y que la misma la decodifique usando JS entonces quedas en lo mismo, ya que los usuarios tienen acceso desde un explorador como Chrome a ver los pedidos que hacen las páginas a la web... Entonces tendrían acceso a la llave decodificada simplemente monitoreando los paquetes de salida que hace la misma. Por seguridad tiene que haber alguien en el medio de la API externa y el usuario.

Comment: Si la letra que suena en la radio esta definida y el servidor sabe cuál es, entonces podrías hacer que el servidor de la letra de la canción a los usuarios. Y que por lo tanto solo este tenga acceso a la llave API.

Comment: En realidad no busco algo super seguro, simplemente no tener que publicar la clave en texto plano. Solo deseo evitar que alguien mirando el código del JS la obtenga de inmediato, o sea, no deseo protegerla de usuarios avanzados sino de principiantes como yo. Si alguien me puede compartir el código de como hacerlo le estaría agradecido.